# Trino with HAProxy - Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl, openssl, haproxy, trino

I have following configuration for Trino 425 cluster, all worked fine with older Presto version:

- 2 coordinators
- 5 workers

I have configured self signed certs in following way :

```
1. Self-Signed CA creation

-  Generate the CA's private key

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out ca-key.pem

-  Generate the self-signed CA cert

openssl req -new -x509 -key ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -days 365

2. Configuration for extensions

Create file ext_server.conf

[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
CN = *.env.de.com
[v3_req]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = presto-01.env.de.com
DNS.2 = presto-02.env.de.com
DNS.3 = presto-03.env.de.com
DNS.4 = presto-04.env.de.com
DNS.5 = presto-05.env.de.com
DNS.6 = haproxy-01.env.de.com


3. 

- Create server's private key 

openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out server-key.pem

- Generate a CSR for the server

openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -out server.csr -config ext_server.conf

- Sign the server's CSR using the CA

openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -days 365 -extfile ext_server.conf -extensions v3_req

- Convert to PKCS12 keystore:

openssl pkcs12 -export -in server-cert.pem -inkey server-key.pem -out server-keystore.p12 -name server -password pass:changeit

- Convert PKCS12 to JKS:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server-keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore server.np.keystore.jks -deststorepass changeit -srcstorepass changeit

4. Create Truststore

keytool -import -keystore server.np.truststore.jks -file ca-cert.pem -alias ca -storepass changeit
```

When I set `discovery.uri` to coordinator URL `presto-01.env.de.com`. Then all works fine, and nodes can communicate with no issues.

However when I set HAProxy with passthrough configuration as below and `discovery.uri` to `haproxy-01.env.de.com` I am getting certs errors.

Haproxy config :

```
defaults
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  log global
  option tcpka
  timeout client 10000
  timeout server 10000
  timeout connect 10000

listen  stats
        bind *:8085
        mode            http
        log             global

        maxconn 20

        stats enable
        stats hide-version
        stats refresh 5s
        stats show-node
        stats auth admin:password
        stats uri  /

frontend f_trino
  bind *:8443 name trino_a
  bind *:8080 name trino_m
  acl rule_monitor dst_port 8080
  use_backend bk_trino_m if rule_monitor
  default_backend bk_trino_a

backend bk_trino_a
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server coordinator-1 presto-01.env.de.com:8443 check
    server coordinator-2 presto-02.env.de.com:8443 check backup

backend bk_trino_m
      server coordinator-1 presto-01.env.de.com:8080 check
      server coordinator-2 presto-02.env.de.com:8080 check backup
```

Error:

```
io.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryException: Announcement failed for https://haproxy-01.env.de.com:8443
    at io.airlift.discovery.client.HttpDiscoveryAnnouncementClient$DiscoveryResponseHandler.handleException(HttpDiscoveryAnnouncementClient.java:194)
    at io.airlift.http.client.jetty.JettyResponseFuture.failed(JettyResponseFuture.java:152)
    at io.airlift.http.client.jetty.BufferingResponseListener.onComplete(BufferingResponseListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.abort(HttpReceiver.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.abortResponse(HttpChannel.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.terminateRequest(HttpSender.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abortRequest(HttpSender.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.lambda$executeAbort$0(HttpSender.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
```